# How do I use wx.ListCtrl in wx.PopupWindow (wxPython) on Windows OS?

Tags: wxpython

I can add wx.ListCtrl into wx.PopupWindow and even scroll it.
The problem is that I cannot click on any of list items.

Python:

```
C:\tmp\python36-64\python.exe
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

wxPython:

```
>>>wx version:
'4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850 msw (phoenix)'
```

I used wxPython demo to create this example.
In Phoenix demo this functionality is commented out.

My test script source on github: [SOURCE](https://github.com/alexbuz/Misc-Scripts/blob/master/list_in_popup_win.py)

Comment: Works with '4.0.0b2'

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Can you actually selecct list item? I'm on '4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850 msw (phoenix)' and cannot do it. I can scroll allright but not select.

Comment: Scroll, select and get the selection printed out, after a tweak to alter self.log.write  to be print

Comment: @RolfofSaxony what's you Python version? thank you!

Comment: Python 3.5.2  
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

Comment: @RolfofSaxony 2.7/3.4/3.5/3.6 32/64 bit on Windows does not work